# How to specify a generic key type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a case where I have a generic query that can return any type of collection and some subqueries that strictly expect return a Decks, Cards or Notes Collection, decks are indexed by name and return array of cards ids, cards by ids and return notes ids and notes by ids and return data.

```js
export type Collection<K extends (number|string), V extends (number|string)> = { [key: K]: V[] }
export type DecksCollection = Collection<string, number>
export type CardsCollection = Collection<number, number>
export type NotesCollection = Collection<number, string>
```

It throw me `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.`

I would like to write the first line correctly since I strictly expect strings or numbers, not both and K must be a number or string since for typescript it's an index.

Comment: It doesn't aswer the question

Comment: @Christopher someone (presumably you?) voted to close this, but IMO you should post your comment as an answer.  Also it works with `{ [key in K]: V[] }` which is probably what they want, since that's not an index signature.

Comment: @LindaPaiste See [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/186177)